# Stripe checkout is not working

Tags: php, stripe-payments

We are use `stripe payments` method in a php script. We are getting the following  error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 
    'Amount must be at least 50 cents' in /stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php:102 
     from API request 'req_7w4X4j80cfWZoS'
Stack trace:
#0 /lib/ApiRequestor.php(216): 
       Stripe\ApiRequestor->handleApiError('{\n "error": {\n...', 400, Array, Array)
#1 /stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php(60): 
       Stripe\ApiRequestor->_interpretResponse('{\n "error": {\n...', 400, Array)
#2 /stripe-php/lib/ApiResource.php(105): 
        Stripe\ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/charges', Array, Array)
#3 stripe-php/lib/ApiResource.php(137): 
         Stripe\ApiResource::_staticRequest('post', '/v1/charges', Array, NULL)
#4 /home/imarkinfo/donogifts.com/stripe-php/lib/Charge.php(37):
          Stripe\ApiResource::_create(Array, NULL)
#5 /form_section.php(81): 
          Stripe\Charge::create(Array)
#6 {main} thrown in stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php on line 102
```

Please suggest how we can fix it

Comment: Code layout and question statement rewording

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You [created the charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) with `amount=1`. As the error message explicitly says, the [minimum amount](https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-is-the-minimum-amount-i-can-charge-with-stripe) is 50 cents. All amounts in Stripe's API are in cents, so `amount` must be at least `50` when creating a charge.

Comment: we have already set price 1

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                "amount" =>  1, // amount in cents, again
                "currency" => "usd",
                "source" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                "description" => "Example charge")

Comment: amount is in cents, $1 is 100 not 1. amount = 1 would charge $.01

Comment: You save my life

Comment: there's a different flag for now that lets you do decimals (ie. `1.01`)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to charge $1 you must set amount=100 as stripe uses cents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to charge the user in `Cents`. if your Amount is in USD, you can convert it to cents by Multiplying with 100.
So if your amount is 5 USD. Convert it by `$amount=5*100`